# show createdAT timestamp according to timezone rather that utc

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am putting following query to see the records:

`select * from dbName.TableName` to get the records .

now what happens is it shows me `createdAt' and`updatedAt' in utc format. So is there a way through which , I can see it in IST (indian standard time) format while querying ?

Comment: What column type are we talking about?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its column type is `DATE` type

Answer (score 0):

You need Select_convert_tz() function of MySql. Have a look at [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Edit based on comment:
query should look like
 to select converted timezone

```
select select_convert_tz(column,'from_timezone','to_timezone') from table where condition
```

or to query based on timezon

```
select * from table where select_convert_tz(column,'from_timezone','to_timezone')>'some value'
```

Comment: as per your suggestion i wrote query `SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename where CONVERT_TZ(createdAt,'+00:00','+5:30');` but somehow, it is not converting it

Comment: whats the result?

Comment: I guess you want use the function in `SELECT` clause rather than in `WHERE`. Otherwise, try adding operator and reference value, since pure function result may be something equivalent to TRUE.